# create a summary of data from some columns to a one column

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, multiple-columns, summary

I have a excel file with 5 columns and more than 1000 rows. column A is customer cod. column B is year of selling machine .column C is type of machine .column D is count of selling. column E is tax.
I want to create a summary in one cell (for example in column I ) to show that each cod in which years buy which types. All types in each year can get in parentheses. for example cod 1001 in 2023 buy type D, B;  in 2022 buy type C;  in 2021 buy type A. so my cod create :2023(D, B); 2022(C); 2021(A)

I attach my code (created via dictionaries by dear VBasic2008) and its results.

```
Sub TransformData()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Write to source array.
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Write.
    Dim sData() As Variant:
    sData = srg.Value
   
    ' Write to the dictionary.
    ' Define.
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, cod As Variant, dabir As Variant, group As Variant
    ' Write.
    For r = 2 To UBound(sData, 1) '   ÊÚÏÇÏ ˜á ÓØÑ
        cod = sData(r, 1)   'cod(key)
          dabir = sData(r, 2)
          group = sData(r, 3)
        If Not dict.Exists(cod) Then
            Set dict(cod) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        If Not dict(cod).Exists(dabir) Then
            Set dict(cod)(dabir) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' string
            dict(cod)(dabir).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        End If
        If Not dict(cod)(dabir).Exists(group) Then
            dict(cod)(dabir)(group) = Empty
        End If
    Next r

   ' Write to the destination array.

   ' Define (initialize).
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To 2)
    r = 1
'    ' Write headers.
    dData(1, 1) = sData(1, 1)
    dData(1, 2) = sData(1, 2) & DST_DATE_TYPE_DELIMITER & sData(1, 3)
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim cKey As Variant, dKey As Variant, dStr As String
    ' Write data.
    For Each cKey In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        dData(r, 1) = cKey
        For Each dKey In dict(cKey).Keys
            dStr = dStr & "; " & dKey & "(" & Join(dict(cKey)(dKey).Keys, ", ") & ")"
        Next dKey
        dStr = Right(dStr, Len(dStr) - Len("; "))
        dData(r, 2) = dStr
        dStr = vbNullString
    Next cKey
    ' Write to the destination range.
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = sws.Range("H1")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(r, 2)
    ' Write.
    drg.Value = dData
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.count - drg.Row - r + 1).Offset(r).Clear
    ' Format.
    With drg
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

my result are here in green area

[image]

now I want to add count summation and tax summation in brackets. for example cod:1001 in 2023 buy 7 type D and -2 type B. so summation of count for cod 1001 in year 2023 is 7+(-2)=5. also the tax. summation of tax for cod 1001 in 2023 is 200,000 + 35,000=235,000. so in result I need this for cod 1001:

2023(D, B)[count=5, tax=235,000];  2022(C)[count=2, tax=20,000];  2021(A)[count=3, tax=150,000]

I attach the sample that in need (green area) in results.

[image]